# Angular: Moving a library into a directory causes issues

Tags: angular-cli

I had created a "libs" directory in the "projects" folder with the intention of placing my libraries in there. However, when I try to run `ng test libraryName`, the CLI is not using the correct path for the library. Instinctively, I believed I had made an error in specifying the path in the angular.json file, but that was not the case. For some reason, placing libraries inside of a directory causes problems.

**Angular Info:**

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.2.9
Node: 10.15.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.10
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.8.9
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.8.9
@angular-devkit/core               0.8.9
@angular-devkit/schematics         0.8.9
@angular/cli                       6.2.9
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   6.2.9
@schematics/angular                0.8.9
@schematics/update                 0.8.9
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.2.2
typescript                         2.9.2
webpack                            4.16.4
```

**Default Project Structure (No Errors):**

[image]

**Desired Project Structure (Causes Errors):**

[image]

**Steps for Reproduction**:

1. Create New Project (`ng new projectName`)
2. Navigate into Project Directory (`cd projectName`)
3. Create Library (`ng generate library libraryName`)
4. Create a directory under "projects" named "libs".
5. Move library into "libs".
6. Modify the paths found for "libraryName" in angular.json to reflect the change made in step 5. (i.e. change path from 'projects/libraryName' to 'projects/**libs**/libraryName'
7. Run `ng test libraryName` (Or `ng build libraryName`/`ng lint libraryName`)
8. Angular CLI will error.

**angular.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angularLibraryGenerateTest": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angularLibraryGenerateTest",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angularLibraryGenerateTest:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angularLibraryGenerateTest:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angularLibraryGenerateTest:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "angularLibraryGenerateTest-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "angularLibraryGenerateTest:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "angularLibraryGenerateTest:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "libraryName": {
      "root": "projects/libs/libraryName",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/libs/libraryName/src",
      "projectType": "library",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr:build",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "projects/libs/libraryName/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "project": "projects/libs/libraryName/ng-package.json"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/libs/libraryName/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/libs/libraryName/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/libs/libraryName/karma.conf.js"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "projects/libs/libraryName/tsconfig.lib.json",
              "projects/libs/libraryName/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angularLibraryGenerateTest"
}
```

I expected `ng test libraryName` to execute the unit tests but instead I get the following error:

```
error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/tsconfig.json'.

Error: error TS5058: The specified path does not exist: 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/tsconfig.json'.
```

**Note:** The path being used is incorrect. It should be 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/**libs**/**libraryName**/tsconfig.json' instead of 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/tsconfig.json'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to adjust the relative path in the `tsconfig.lib.json`.
As you move the library one directory deeper, some relative paths must be adjusted.

**modified projects/libs/library-name/tsconfig.lib.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../../out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Three directories up instead of two.
This is necessary for e.g. the `ng build` command. **The same applies to the `projects/libs/library-name/tsconfig.spec.json`**, which is necessary for the `ng test` command.

---

> Note: The path being used is incorrect. It should be 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/libs/libraryName/librarytsconfig.json' instead of 'C:/Users/user/projectName/projects/tsconfig.json'

It's directly vivce versa. 
The path in the console output is correct as the inital `tsconfig.lib.json` has relative paths like this `../../tsconfig.json` and therefore ends up in `/projectName/projects/` instead of just `projectName/` where the `tsconfig.json` is located that should be extended.

Comment: I made the changes to `projects/libs/library-name/tsconfig.lib.json` as mentioned above. However, the CLI is still looking for `tsconfig.json` under the projects directory (i.e. receiving the same error as mentioned in the original post)

Comment: sry of course you have to do the same in the `tsconfig.spec.json`. Did this 'automatically', because I tried `test` and `build` command, but didn't mention it. I will adapt my answer.